# How to connect to MS-SQL 2012 and MS-SQL 2008 on same machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a an application where you can log on to either MS-SQL 2012 and MS-SQL 2008. 
Fields that can be defined are:
Server IP
Database Name
User Id and Password
Schema Prefix

Previously I had no issues with this.
Now I am puzzled.
I am told MS-SQL 2012 and MS-SQL 2008 are on same box with same IP.
I googled this arrangement and it is quite OK to do that.

I have no mental picture of how connecting to one or both of these servers might be carried out.

Are these two installs folded into one? Do they listen on the same port 1433?

Should I be able to access using just the 4 fields I can specify?
Server IP,Database Name, User Id and Password and Schema Prefix.

Help if you can, please ;-)

Tony

Comment: You need to include the instance name in your connection string. You also shouldn't tag ever dbms out there.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not enough information to reach separate SQL Server instances on the same server.

When installing multiple instances of SQL Server, only one instance can be a default instaince, the other instances have to be named instances. Thus, you also need the instance name to reach one of the databases.

However, if the IP address is not strictly only an IP address but a string, you can include the instance name. Example:

```
123.14.314.73\sql2012
```

(Note: IP addreses with components above 255 are reserved for examples and movies. ;) )

Comment: And correct me if I am wrong but i think the Sql Server Browser Service should be running in order to just connect to the instance with the server name and the instance name.

Comment: @Blim: Yes. It is started automatically by default when you install multiple instances, so that shouldn't be a problem: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087%28v=sql.105%29.aspx